# Bottom_nav_menu disappears when transitioning from an activity to a fragment in Java (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, navigation, android-navigation-bar

Using 
`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .add(android.R.id.content, new ScanFragment ()).commit();`
in Activity to transfer to a Fragment that contains bottom navigation bar. The fragment appears without the bottom navigation bar.

Please help me figure out how to transition from activity to fragment without losing the navigation bar in the process. Thanks a lot